# Can this be a valid sentence?

Tags: particles, structure

私はたくさんのパンを食べますとたくさんの水を飲むます
Yes, we can omit the 私は but the rest just sounds weird to me.
This is what it should mean: I eat a lot of bread and drink a lot of water.
Thank you!

Comment: Please make 飲むます -> 飲みます fix in conjugation, which is unrelated to main topic of question.

Comment: I think you should clarify what your doubts are about.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence does not have intended meaning. と can be used to create list of nouns, but NOT to create list of causally-unrelated clauses containing verbs.

For conjoining of multiple causally-unrelated clauses, verbs in non-last clauses should be either in [連用形]{れんようけい}/Continuative form <sub>(this may sound more formal or literary)</sub> or 〜て form <sub>(called Gerund or Subordinative Converb by some linguists)</sub>:

> 私はたくさんのパンを食べたくさんの水を飲みます

> 私はたくさんのパンを食べてたくさんの水を飲みます

There are situations where と can conjoin clauses, but then it is some type of conditional ("if", "when"). I think that original sentence from this question would mean "If I eat a lot of bread, then I drink a lot of water.".

Comment: ? This seems incorrect. Neither of your example sentences are grammatical. Neither of those forms can precede と like in your examples.

Comment: @jogloran I fixed typos.

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence reads,

> If I eat a lot of bread, then I drink a lot of water.

と does not work as the conjunction *and* to connect verbs.  と only means *and* when connecting nouns together.  When と follows a verb, it generally means "whenever" or "if".

To say "I eat a lot of bread and I drink a lot of water",
there are a number of choices.

You could just say,

> パンをたくさん食べます。水をたくさん飲みます。

> パンをたくさん食べますし。水をたくさん飲みます。

> パンをたくさん食べて水をたくさん飲みます

though this last example sounds like you first eat a lot of bread and then drink a lot of water.

You could also say,

> パンをたくさん食べ 水をたくさん飲みます

Comment: The particle し in this sense is used as a conjunctive particle like パンもたくさん食べますし、水もたくさん飲みます. It also has usage as sentence-final particle, but it means something different (such as indicating reason).

Comment: thank you very much!